# How to dynamically change the layout of a displayed Activity containing a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager

I have an Activity containing a ViewPager. There's a button which allows the user to alternate between 2 layout for the same activity.
Everything works fine except for the ViewPager which doesn't display anyting once the layout has been updated. I need to exit reopen the activity to see its content.

```
private void updateLayout() {
    setContentView(getLayoutId());

    this.viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    this.viewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), getLayoutId());
    this.viewPager.setAdapter(this.viewPagerAdapter);
    this.viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}


public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

...

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TAG + "_" + this.layoutId + "_" + position;
    }
...
}
```

I try adding some code to delete existing fragments but it doesn't help:

```
final List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
            if (fragments != null) {
                //getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().clear();

                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                for (final Fragment fragment : fragments) {
                    try {
                        //You can perform additional check to remove some (not all) fragments:
                        if (fragment instanceof MyViewPagerAdapter) { 
                            ft.remove(fragment);
                        }
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        Crashlytics.logException(e);
                    }
                }
                ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
```

Any idea on how to achieve that ?

Comment: post all your `Activity` code

Comment: I already displayed the whole code used to update the layout while the activity is displayed. I'm just asking what am I missing.  Do I need to remove the fragments like I tried even though it's not working ?